# Crystal Report XI (SP4) using DataSet cannot display parameters

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005, oracle10g, report

We are using CR XI Developer Edition on server side (a Web-service).

For sercurity reasons, we extract all SQL (we only use SQL in CR) from CR template and run it to get DataSets. After that, we assign DataSets back to CR.

Everything is ok (our server can display CR with or without subreports or multi-commands in report) except Parameters.

We cannot display parameters on CR even we try this command:

```
foreach (ParameterPair nvp in prms)
     doc.SetParameterValue(nvp.Name, nvp.Value);
```

Please help me.
We are using C# VS2005 against Oracle 10g R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if create report by assigning DataSets, parameters seem to be omitted. So that, if still want to display parameters on report we have to assign parameters' text to text object in reports before showing it.